# Wildcard certificate for apps

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, https, certificate

I want to set up apps over https.

If my certificate is for *.domain.com, should it work for *.apps.domain.com?

I am receiving "Mismatched Address" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not work, as wild card works on 1st level. i.e `*.domain.com` is good `sub1.domain.com` and `sub2.domain.com` but not for `*.app.domain`.

You need a wild certificate for this `"*.apps.domain.com"` which will cover all the dynamic apps url.